# Navigate to tag in a new tab if not already opened, like `tab drop`?

Tags: tabbed-user-interface, tags, navigation

What I expect from "tab-tag" navigation is the following behaviour: when need to jump to a tag:

- if the corresponding file is already opened in a window, navigate to it
- if it is not, open the buffer in a new tab

This is the behaviour of this command I like:

```
:tab drop file.txt
```

But it is *not* the behaviour of `<C-]>`.

How may I get this navigation style?

---

I am aware that there already are [plenty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908269) of [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53y9231/3719101) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6069279/3719101) on the [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6536049/3719101), none of which provides the exact behaviour I am looking for.

---

This is now the object of a [feature request](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1292) to vim, unless I have been missing something :\

Comment: Does setting 'switchbuf'' help?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt It does not. Setting `switchbuf=usetab` or `switchbuf=newtab` has no effect on `<c-]>` behaviour :(

Answer (score 5):

Put this in your vimrc:

```
map <C-]> :TabExpand 1<CR>

command -nargs=1 TabExpand call HandleTabTagExpand( <f-args> )

let s:commentchar = """

function HandleTabTagExpand(tagnumber)
    let tagident = expand("<cword>")
    redir @a
    try
        sil exe "tselect ".tagident
    catch /^Vim(\a\+):E433:/ " no tag file
        echom "No tag file found."
        return
    catch /^Vim(\a\+):E426:/ " tag not found
        echom "Tag not found."
        return
    endtry
    redir END
    let tagresults = split(@a, "\n")
    let tagmatches = []
    let linenum = 0
    for line in tagresults
        if linenum % 3 != 1
            " every third line contains the file names
            let linenum = linenum + 1
            continue
        endif
        " figure out where the filename actually starts
        " (it's usually column 32, but it might be farther)
        " one before 32 is 31, but index is 30 since arrays begin at zero
        let filestart = 30
        let c = line[filestart]
        while (filestart < strlen(line))
            let filestart = filestart + 1
            if c == " "
                break
            endif
            let c = line[filestart]
        endwhile
        " store the parsed match in an array
        call add(tagmatches, strpart(line, filestart))
        let linenum = linenum + 1
    endfor
    " navigate to the match specified by tagnumber
    try
        exe "tab drop ".tagmatches[a:tagnumber-1]
    catch /^Vim(\a\+):E471:/ " argument required (means no tag found)
        echom "Tag not found."
    endtry
    let done = 0
    let matchcount = 0
    let f_line = ""
    while done < 1 && matchcount < 1000
        sil exe "/".tagident
        let f_line = getline(".")
        let matchcount = matchcount + 1
        if match(f_line, "^\s+".s:commentchar) < 0
            let done = 1
        endif
    endwhile
    let f_index = stridx( f_line, tagident )
    sil exe "normal 0"
    sil exe "normal ".f_index."l"
endfunction
```

What this does is silently execute tselect, redirecting its output to register `a`. Tselect does the same thing as tag or tjump but it doesn't actually perform the jump, only the lookup, and returns a list of results. Without using `:redir` those results wouldn't be stored anywhere that we can get at them.

Next, it pulls from register `a` the tag output returned from tselect and parses it into a line by line array. The output contains other stuff we don't care about. All we need to know is that every second line (mod 3) has a matching file name starting (normally) at column 32, except where the other stuff in front is longer, so we have to account for that by finding the first space beginning at column 31. The character after the first space is where the file will always begin, regardless of what preceeds it.

Finally we parse the file names one by one, and pass one of those filenames to tab drop, which should open a new tab if one isn't already open, or jump over to the already-open tab if there is one.

Now you can just type

`:TabExpand n`

(where n is an integer) and it will open existing tab if there is one, or a new tab, for the *n*th matching tag. The -1 in the array address gives us more user-friendly behavior: when we give it a 1, meaning the first match, it results in zero which is the actual first index in the array.

If you want to jump immediately to the first tag match, you can use the default mapping for tag jump (`<C-]>`) because we have remapped it to call `:TabExpand 1`.

The last part of the code ignores commented lines (based on the specified comment character), and jumps to the exact line and cursor location of the next tag match. You can press `n` to cycle through further matches in the same file.

Comment: Thank you for this insight into the inner tag functionnalities. However, this function opens the.. tag file `./tags` instead of opening the destination file, right? `&tags` contains `./tags,./TAGS,$HOME/.vimtags,tags,TAGS` on my machine, so the last command is just `tab drop ./tags` for me, whereas I am expecting to open, say `definitions.[hpp|py|java|R|whatever]`. How is the result of `tselect` supposed to be used in your procedure?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. There has got to be somewhere that vim actually stores the tag lookup results. Let me take a look and I'll update my answer accordingly. I must have seen something on my machine that looked like a tag result instead of a tag file. EDIT: Answer has been updated and is verified to now work.

Comment: Thanks for this deep work into the topic :) Too bad that the function does not navigate to the actual tag location.

Comment: @Iago-lito I plan to update it with that feature, just haven't had time.

Comment: @lago-lito I've updated my answer so that it jumps to the exact tag location.

Comment: Arf, still not there ^ ^ I have tried the function on [this very small example](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4wrqI2bz3uaMno5TWVfS0tPWGc), hitting <c-]> when on `Host` in `main.py` makes me successively navigate to `Host.py` line 1, then line 5, then line 6, then it loops over. But line 5 is the only relevant line :\

Comment: Ah I see. Because I'm using basic search to jump there, and not the default tag jump, it's not ignoring commented lines as the normal tag functionality would do. Hmm, that is definitely a conundrum. Looks like we're 90% of the way there. Let me see if I can fix this last part.

Comment: I've come up with a way to skip commented lines. The problem here is, comment characters are different depending on which language you are talking about. For example, Python uses quotes to start comments, so we could skip those lines, but that could be incorrect for other languages where it would be important not to ignore lines beginning with quotes. So I'll include a configuration setting for which comment character to look for.

Comment: I updated my answer, and I verified that the current version of code works even with the small example code you linked.

Comment: Hmm, I think there is no need to add extra code for handling these comment stuff. Have you noticed that the `tags` file itself contains the unambiguous regex you are looking for? Why not using it, this would be the last step ;)

Comment: That would be ideal, however keep in mind that you can have multiple tag files. The parsing algorithm to search through all of them and find the regex you are talking about would be way, way bigger than the extra code for handling comments. If you want to write that code, be my guest. As of now, it does what you want, even for the example code you linked. If there is some additional scenario that is failing, I don't think it's worth writing a whole new tag system just to fix that one tiny scenario. The code is practically doing that already.

Comment: Ayy, I understand. Too bad we need to re-implement the tag functionality just for this opening behaviour :( Is there no other way ? The thing is that vim's `tag` functionality already features handling of multiple tag files, navigating back, ask for user input if several possibilities arise, *etc.* My feeling is that the work that you've done (great, by the way) should not be our responsibility, don't you feel the same? We just need a new way to *navigate* to a location once it has been targetted. Not to actually *find* it by ourselves :\

Comment: Right, it's essentially a missing feature. One would expect a "tab tag" command or something like that. The same tag jump behavior, except it opens in a new tab, and if the tab is already open, it just jumps to that tab and goes to the tag location.

Comment: Do you think this deserves a request on the official vim repo?

Comment: Possibly. I wouldn't expect much from them; contacting anyone is hard enough, much less getting a suggested feature pushed through the pipeline. But it's worth a try.

Comment: Okay, so let's [try](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1292) this ;)